# How to MSDeploy an ASP.NET Core app from command line? (csproj not project.json)

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-core, msdeploy, continuous-deployment

Can ASP.NET Core apps be deployed via msdeploy.exe and a .pubxml definition similar to what was possible for pre-.NET Core?  This is the command that I've used previously:

`msbuild myproj.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<profile-name>`.

If not, what is the preferred way to deploy an ASP.NET Core app from the command line?

Comment: I have the exact opposite problem. I can't publish with VS most often, but can with the VS dev command prompt using MSBuild/DeployOnBuild (which works like a charm).

Comment: MSDeploy is for IIS only, which no longer matches the goal of going cross platform with .NET Core. So I guess that's why Microsoft does not make what you want working by default. Can you try out `dotnet publish`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/web-publishing-vs

Comment: actually many of the publish profile functions are implemented by the web sdk so that most publish profiles should work. the VS UI also calls into them. what is the exact error you are getting? can you share the publishing profile?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I get a long list of errors indicating that essentially every .net namespace cannot be found, i.e., `The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?`.  I've updated my answer above with the exact command that I'm running.

Comment: do you run `dotnet restore` as part of the publish process?

Comment: Yes, I `dotnet restore` before `dotnet build`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To deploy your asp.net core app to Azure web App simply do the following steps:

```
1. dotnet publishsomeproject.csproj -c release -o someDirectory
2. msdeploy.exe  -verb:sync -source:contentPath="someDirectory" -dest:contentPath="webAppName",ComputerName="https://WebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/msdeploy.axd",UserName="username",Password="password",IncludeAcls="False",AuthType="Basic"
-enablerule:AppOffline -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:20 -verbose
```

Username and Password can be retrieved or set on the deployment preview section in the web app in Azure portal. I have set an env path for my `msdeploy.exe` which can be found usually here `C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3`.

Answer (score 4):

You can find documentation on the commandline usage here : 
https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/dev/README.md#microsoftnetsdkpublish

You can use any of the below commands to publish using MSDeploy from commandline

```
msbuild WebApplication.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<MsDeployProfileName> /p:Password=<DeploymentPassword>
```

or

```
dotnet publish WebApplication.csproj /p:PublishProfile=<MsDeployProfileName> /p:Password=<DeploymentPassword>
```

You can find samples of various profiles here - https://github.com/vijayrkn/PublishProfiles/tree/master/samples

To fix the errors. make sure you run restore first before running the publish command:

```
dotnet restore
```

Comment: unfortunatelly, it only creates local bin folder and does not send anything to the destination even if it is defined in publish profile...

Comment: worked for me, I created a web deploy profile from visual studio and used it in command line and published to remote IIS, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One approach using the `dotnet` cli tool is the `dotnet publish` command.

```
dotnet restore
dotnet publish -c Release -o output
```

This will restore all NuGet dependencies and then create a release build in a folder named `output`.  You can then "xcopy deploy" it, add to a Dockerfile or do whatever else you need to do.

Note that this works with `csproj` based projects using newer versions of the `dotnet` cli tool (which no longer support `project.json` files).

Comment: Thank you for the suggest.  I am specifically hoping to msdeploy; I understand that I can use dotnet publish to _prepare_ an application for deployment, but that isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry about that.  I see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869701/how-do-i-deploy-net-core-rc2-projects-via-msbuild-msdeploy looks like it has some promising info.  It looks like you may want to run the above `dotnet` commands and use the output of that for `msdeploy`.